# Transformers tokenizer returns overlapping tokens. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have been trying to do some token classification using huggingface transformers. I'm seeing instances where the tokenizer returns overlapping tokens. Sometimes (but not always) this will result in the model giving me an entity such that the (start, end) correspond to where the overlap starts and ends, but it lists the entity word as the empty string.

Here is a simple example to illustrate where it returns overlapping tokens:

```
>>> import transformers

>>> tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained ('xlm-roberta-large-finetuned-conll03-english')

>>> text = "No clue."
>>> tokens = tokenizer(text)

>>> tokens[0].offsets
[(0, 0), (0, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (0, 0)]

>>> [text[start:end] for (start,end) in tokens[0].offsets[1:-1]]
['No', 'c', 'clu', 'e', '.']
```

The examples where the model returns the overlapping character as a named entity are quite a bit longer. I can include them if needed, but shouldn't the tokenizer always return a non-overlapping set of tokens?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Persian. This piece of code can help to remove some unnecessary tokens:

```
def word_mapper(text: str, offset_mapping: list) -> list:
  return [
    text[char_start: char_end]
    for index, (char_start, char_end) in enumerate(offset_mapping[:-1])
    if offset_mapping[index][0] != offset_mapping[index + 1][0]
  ]
```